# fusion table autocomplete text search

Tags: google-maps, search, autocomplete, google-fusion-tables

I went through [this link](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/autocomplete) which shows a fusion table map layer with auto complete search box. But in this example, only the first 500 rows of fusion table is indexing in auto complete.

Find the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HnwA2/2/) below for the reference.

```
  function initAutoComplete(tableId) {
    // Retrieve the unique store names using GROUP BY workaround.
    var queryText = encodeURIComponent(
        "SELECT 'FB_INDO_2000', COUNT() " +
        'FROM ' + tableId + " GROUP BY 'FB_INDO_2000'");
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
        'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);

    query.send(function(response) {
      var numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();

      // Create the list of results for display of autocomplete.
      var results = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        results.push(response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0));
      }

      // Use the results to create the autocomplete options.
      $('#store').autocomplete({
        source: results,
        minLength: 2
      });
    });
  }
```

**EDIT:** As *geocodezip* suggested, i updated my [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HnwA2/3/) by changing the query to FT API v1 as,

```
var queryText = encodeURIComponent(
        "SELECT 'FB_INDO_2000', COUNT() " + 'FROM ' + tableId + " GROUP BY 'FB_INDO_2000'");
     var queryUrlHead = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=';
    var queryUrlTail = '&key=AIzaSyCAI2GoGWfLBvgygLKQp5suUk3RCG7r_ME';
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(queryUrlHead + queryText + queryUrlTail);
```

But unable to achieve auto complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Visualization API is limited to 500 results from a FusionTable.](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code#chartTools)

Use the [FusionTables v1 API instead](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code#ftAPIv1), it does not have that restriction.

working version of your code:

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20'FB_INDO_2000'%20FROM%201E9BosnI16GISRmTBkINI2aWlYVdZae46v8jClAc%20GROUP%20BY%20'FB_INDO_2000'&callback=drawMap&key=AIzaSyCAI2GoGWfLBvgygLKQp5suUk3RCG7r_ME" type="text/javascript" ></script>

   function drawMap(response) {
      var numRows = response.rows.length;

      // Create the list of results for display of autocomplete.
      var results = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        results.push(response.rows[i][0]);
      }

      // Use the results to create the autocomplete options.
      $('#store').autocomplete({
        source: results,
        minLength: 2
      });
   };
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G88qp/1/)

Comment: Myself modified my fiddle to FT API v1 here: http://jsfiddle.net/HnwA2/3/ but the auto complete is not working. Where is me wrong?

Comment: You are not using the Fusion Tables v1 API correctly (you are still using the google.visualization.Query call, you need to replace that by the equivalent v1 call). [example using FT v1 API](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=48.470294&lng=-119.353782&zoom=2&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20%20kml_4326%,%name%20FROM&tableid=1foc3xO9DyfSIF6ofvN0kp2bxSfSeKog5FbdWdQ&where=name%20contains%20%27State%27)

Comment: updated my answer with a working fiddle (and the code required to make it work)

Comment: Check the javascript console:`Uncaught ReferenceError: queryresponse is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the Google Visualization API to get the data and it has a limit of 500 rows.  The FT 1.0 API via JSONP does not as @Swires pointed out.
See this example: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/basic_jsonp_request

Comment: Myself modified my fiddle to FT API v1 here: jsfiddle.net/HnwA2/3 but the auto complete is not working. Where is me wrong?